# How do I create multiple divs popup on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I need a help with a project.

Is there a way of creating multiple popups on the same page with the code I have?  I can only get to open the first one... I know that it has to do something with the script but for the life of me, I don't know what I have to do and there's nothing on w3school to help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">

<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Popup 1!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup 1 Content</span>
</div>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Popup 2!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">Popup 2 Content!</span>
</div>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById('myPopup');
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing to the same popup element i.e. element having myPopup id for both of the on click event, when it should be depending upon which div was clicked.
By using mouse event(currentTarget property) you will be able to get the selected(clicked) element and by traversing to it's child element you will be able to toggle classes of appropriate pop ups
[plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/hT8M3Fqq6Ieqk7cinFjG?p=preview)

```
function myFunction(event) {
  event.target.children[0].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

and change the onclick events myFunction() to pass the event parameter

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(event)">
```

Comment: would this still work when I have an image for the popup link ie.

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png">
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup 1 Content</span>
</div>

Comment: Try the plunkr link, change it the way you want, and let me know, if you are not able to, anything is achievable, just the implementation might change a little bit, if you face any issues with image let me know, I would be happy to help. And I would suggest you to watch videos and get your basics straight, else it would be harder for you as this is most basic question that you have asked

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try this**

```js
$(function(){
$('.popup').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('show').siblings().removeClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.popup.show .popuptext {
  visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup">Popup 1!
  <span class="popuptext">Popup 1 Content</span>
</div>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<div class="popup">Popup 2!
  <span class="popuptext">Popup 2 Content!</span>
</div>
```